# Send Notifications to Blackberry Hub from Android App

Tags: android, notifications, blackberry-10

How do I send and handle notifications from an Android app in the BlackBerry hub? I am using the Android runtime on BlackBerry 10.  It does not work out of the box if I use Android notifications the regular way.

I was at the BlackBerry mini jam in Hamburg yesterday, November 27th, 2012. The marketing guy responsible for the Android runtime said there are definitely apps which are able to do this, however he could not provide me with details on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dev alpha device try flashing it with beta 4 which includes support for C2DM (push notifications).

https://developer.blackberry.com/blackberry10devalphas/update

If using the simulator, just download the latest version of the simulator.

https://developer.blackberry.com/develop/simulator/index.html

Comment: Hi i have installed the latest Version on my dev device. I know it supports C2DM, but my app does not use C2DM but sends regukar (timer based) android notifications.

Answer (score 0):

According to RIM Support a working release of the Blackberry Hub should be included since BB 10 10.0.9.2264 (I am on 10.9.9.339 which might be the problem)